# Faster and shorter way to check if a cookie exists

Tags: javascript, cookies

What is the shorter and faster way to know if a cookie **has a value** or **exists**?

I'm using this to know if **exists**:

```
 document.cookie.indexOf('COOKIENAME=')== -1
```

This to know if **has a value**

```
 document.cookie.indexOf('COOKIENAME=VALUE')== -1
```

Any better? Any problems on this method?

Comment: "Has a value" as in "has any value" or "has exactly this value"?

Comment: I'm going to name my cookie, `MYCOOKIENAME`, and give it a value of `VALUES`. What do you think is going to happen?

Comment: Well, indexOf would only evaluate correct if you check for the containment of a String in a cookie, it doesn't match a complete name, in that case the above would return `false` therefore giving you the wrong result.

Comment: Shouldn't that be  document.cookie.indexOf('COOKIENAME=') != -1 if we want to check if a cookie exists with that name..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest writing a little helper function to avoid what zzzzBov mentioned in the comment

- The way you use indexOf, it  would only evaluate correct if you check for the containment of a String in a cookie, it doesn't match a complete name, in that case the above would return false therefore giving you the wrong result.

---

```
function getCookie (name,value) {
    if(document.cookie.indexOf(name) == 0) //Match without a ';' if its the firs
        return -1<document.cookie.indexOf(value?name+"="+value+";":name+"=")
    else if(value && document.cookie.indexOf("; "+name+"="+value) + name.length + value.length + 3== document.cookie.length) //match without an ending ';' if its the last
        return true
    else { //match cookies in the middle with 2 ';' if you want to check for a value
        return -1<document.cookie.indexOf("; "+(value?name+"="+value + ";":name+"="))
    }
}
getCookie("utmz") //false
getCookie("__utmz" ) //true
```

---

However, this seems to be a bit slow, so giving it an other approach with splitting them
Those are two other possibilities

```
function getCookie2 (name,value) {
    var found = false;
    document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(e) {
        var cookie = e.split("=");
        if(name == cookie[0].trim() && (!value || value == cookie[1].trim())) {
            found = true;
        }
    })
    return found;
}
```

This one, using the native forEach loop and splitting the cookie array

```
function getCookie3 (name,value) {
    var found = false;
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (var i = 0,ilen = cookies.length;i<ilen;i++) {
         var cookie = cookies[i].split("=");
         if(name == cookie[0].trim() && (!value || value == cookie[1].trim())) {
              return found=true;
         }
     }
     return found;
};
```

And this, using an old for loop, which has the advantage of being able to early return the for loop if a cookie is found

Taking a look on [JSPerf](http://jsperf.com/cookietest) the last 2 aren't even that slow and only return true if theres really a cookie with the name or value, respectively

I hope you understand what i mean

Comment: I'm looking for a method to match the exactly name/value. Thank you any way.

Comment: you mean if theres a cookie named "MyCookieA" and cookie "CookieA", when looking for CookieA you want match both of them

Answer (score 4):

Apparently:

```
document.cookie.indexOf("COOKIENAME=VALUE");
```

For me, [is faster](http://jsperf.com/cookie-access), but only slightly.

As the test shows, surprisingly, it's even faster to split the cookie up into arrays first:

```
document.cookie.split(";").indexOf("COOKIENAME=VALUE");
```

Comment: For me it isn't either, it depends on the browser and the environment

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) for this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>

function isCookieExists(cookiename) {
    return (typeof $.cookie(cookiename) !== "undefined");
}
```